# Como concatenar uma data + string ao passar propriedade pro componente?

Tags: angular

Estou usando um componente do `kendoUi` que preciso passar na propriedade `[title]` minha variável `local.LocalNome` e `local.LocalDataCadastro`, porém eu preciso de aplicar o pipe de date na minha variável de data.

Tentei algo como:

```
<kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let local of locaisList" [title]="local.LocalCadastroData | date + local.LocalNome">
```

Dessa forma eu recebo:

> Unexpected token '+' at column 32 in [local.LocalCadastroData | date +
>   local.LocalNome]

Como eu posso usar minhas duas variáveis pro `title` e aplicar o `pipe` date?

Comment: Qual o valor do seu ```local.LocalNome``` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar a propriedade **`title`** sem fazer o property binding inserindo no valor de title as duas variáveis em forma de **interpolação - {{ }}**:

```
title="{{local.LocalCadastroData | date}} - {{ local.LocalNome}}"
```

Pode ver o funcionamento [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendu)